# ANSI C, integer to string without variadic functions

Tags: c, string, integer, itoa

I'm currently working with a PLC that supports ANSI C, but uses its own flavour of the GNU compiler, which doesn't compile any variadic functions and things like itoa. So using sprintf & co. isn't an option for converting integers to strings. Can anyone guide me to a site where a robust, sprintf- free implementation of itoa is listed or post a suitable algorithm here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So it does not support ANSI C.

Comment: Well yes. This is indeed an ongoing discussion with the SPC providers marketing department ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is from K&R:

```
void itoa(int n, char s[])
{
    int i, sign;

    if ((sign = n) < 0)  /* record sign */
        n = -n;          /* make n positive */
    i = 0;
    do {       /* generate digits in reverse order */
        s[i++] = n % 10 + '0';   /* get next digit */
    } while ((n /= 10) > 0);     /* delete it */
    if (sign < 0)
        s[i++] = '-';
    s[i] = '\0';
    reverse(s);
}
```

`reverse()` just reverses a string.

Comment: Use this version with care as it can overflow the buffer.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  The caller has to know if the buffer has enough space or not.  Just like `sprintf()`.

Comment: Which is why you should never use `sprintf()` and only use `snprintf()`

Comment: I agree with you, if you replace "never" with "almost never".  In general, one should prefer `snprintf()`.  But if one is sure that the target buffer has the required size, `sprintf()` is fine too.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996374/convert-integer-into-an-array/1996500#1996500 for example.