# Finding a Specific Digit of a Number

Tags: c++, integer, digit

I'm trying to find the `n`th digit of an integer of an arbitrary length.  I was going to convert the integer to a string and use the character at index n...

`char Digit = itoa(Number).at(n);`

...But then I realized the `itoa` function isn't standard.  Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: sprintf? (C rather than C++, but it wil work :))

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`(number/intPower(10, n))%10`

just define the function `intPower`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use the % operator and / for integer division in a loop. (Given integer n >= 0, n % 10 gives the units digit, and n / 10 chops off the units digit.)

Answer (score 1):

Itoa is in stdlib.h.

You can also use an alternative itoa:
[Alternative to itoa() for converting integer to string C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228005/alternative-to-itoa-for-converting-integer-to-string-c)
or
[ANSI C, integer to string without variadic functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138209/ansi-c-integer-to-string-without-variadic-functions)

Answer (score 1):

```
number = 123456789
n = 5

tmp1 = (int)(number / 10^n);   // tmp1 = 12345
tmp2 = ((int)(tmp1/10))*10;    // tmp2 = 12340
digit = tmp1 - tmp2;           // digit = 5
```

Comment: Note that `^` is bitlevel XOR in C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ostringstream to convert to a text string, but
a function along the lines of:

```
char nthDigit(unsigned v, int n)
{
    while ( n > 0 ) {
        v /= 10;
        -- n;
    }
    return "0123456789"[v % 10];
}
```

should do the trick with a lot less complications.  (For
starters, it handles the case where n is greater than the number
of digits correctly.)

-- 
James Kanze

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible to avoid conversion to string by means of the function **log10**, int *cmath*, which returns the 10th-base logarithm of a number (roughly its length if it were a string):

```
unsigned int getIntLength(int x)
{
    if ( x == 0 )
            return 1;
    else    return std::log10( std::abs( x ) ) +1;
}

char getCharFromInt(int n, int x)
{
    char toret = 0;
    x = std::abs( x );
    n = getIntLength( x ) - n -1;

    for(; n >= 0; --n) {
        toret = x % 10;
        x /= 10;
    }

    return '0' + toret;
}
```

I have tested it, and works perfectly well (negative numbers are a special case). Also, it must be taken into account that, in order to find tthe nth element, you have to "walk" backwards in the loop, subtracting from the total int *length*.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

A direct answer is:

```
char Digit = 48 + ((int)(Number/pow(10,N)) % 10 );
```

You should include the `<math>` library

Answer (score 0):

```
const char digit = '0' + number.at(n);
```

Assuming `number.at(n)` returns a decimal digit in the range 0...9, that is.

Comment: I can't convert `number` to a string to use `.at(n)`, though.  `itoa` isn't standard.

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach:

```
template<int base>
int nth_digit(int value, int digit)
{
    return (value / (int)pow((double)base, digit)) % base;
}
```

Just lets you do the same thing for different base numbers (e.g. 16, 32, 64, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `itoa` is the [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) method. So, you could simply do:

```
char digit = to_string(number)[index]
```

Comment: Need to handle out of bounds.