# Sort numbers according to n-th term

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting

I know how to sort an array(i.e. bubble sort) but I don't have any idea how I can sort an array according to n-th term. Could you give me idea or example if there is? Thank you for all appreciated answer.
**@edit:** how can be the program sensed a number with zeros I mean for 1 program sense 0001 or 00001 .... ?

```
Example:
2 --> nth digit
4 45 62 1 900 105 --> inputs
```

Output:
  0**0**1 0**0**4 1**0**5 9**0**0 0**4**5 0**6**5

---

```
void bubble_sort(int iarr[], int num) {
   int i, j, k, temp;

   printf("\nUnsorted Data:");
   for (k = 0; k < num; k++) {
      printf("%5d", iarr[k]);
   }

   for (i = 1; i < num; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < num - 1; j++) {
         if (iarr[j] > iarr[j + 1]) {
            temp = iarr[j];
            iarr[j] = iarr[j + 1];
            iarr[j + 1] = temp;
         }
      }

      printf("\nAfter pass %d : ", i);
      for (k = 0; k < num; k++) {
         printf("%5d", iarr[k]);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: why voted down ? i think it is a good question. Please regard.

Comment: Post the bubble sort code and then we can adjust it.

Comment: @chux it has been added

Comment: To sense the difference between "0001" and "00001", code needs to read data into something else besides just `int`.  This makes the issue substantially different as an `int` does not distinguish the number of leading `'0'` when converted from text to `int`.  If this is a concern, suggest posting sample input and the code that reads input.

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer is that your comparison function needs to look at the n-th digit instead of the whole number.

So if your original comparison was something like:

```
if (a < b)     // handle a before b case
elseif (b < a) // handle b before a case
```

you'll want to change it to be:

```
aDigit = getNthDigit(a, n);
bDigit = getNthDigit(b, n);

if (aDigit < bDigit)     // handle a before b case
elseif (bDigit < aDigit) // handle b before a case
```

You'll also have to implement `getNthDigit`, which would involve integer division and modulus operators.

Comment: it is working but the program can't sense 1 as 001 What can I do ?

Comment: `int getNthDigit(int x,int y){
      return fmod((x / power(10, y)), 10);}` is it right ?

Comment: @user3674483 Think you mean `pow()`.  [`pow()` may be imprecise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923249/unusual-output-from-pow) and cause issues with integer math.  This approach also can return + and - answers.  OP has not posted sample input yet, so we do not know if negative numbers are important.

Comment: `int getNthDigit(int x,int y){
        return (abs(x) / pow(10, y)) % 10;}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [qsort](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) for what a generic sort function requires.  For your specific question, look at the sort algorithm you want to implement (i.e. bubble sort), and replace comparisons of elements with a function call to an order function.  Your compare function should then extract the second digit and compare those digits.

Based on your code, you should change `if (iarr[j] > iarr[j + 1])` with `if(comp_gt(iarr[j], iarr[j + 1]))`.  And, I would implement `comp_gt` by

```
int comp_gt(int a, int b)
{
    int a_second_digit = (a / 10) % 10;
    int b_second_digit = (b / 10) % 10;

    return (a_second_digit < b_second_digit);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that you sort the numbers based on their n-th digit.

In the example you have, you see that the bolded digits (the second digit in every number) are the ones who define the order of the output.

Here is an example on how you can solve it (I am tuning it right now, because the method it uses to find a digit is wrong):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void quickSort(int a[], int first, int last, int n_th);
int pivot(int a[], int first, int last, int n_th);
void swap(int* a, int* b);
int n_th_digit(int number, int n);
void print(int array[], const int N);

int main() {
  int test[] = { 7, 9, 1, 3, 6, 5, 2, 4 };
  int N = sizeof(test) / sizeof(int);
  int n_th = 0;  // digit(from the end) to sort by

  printf("Size of test array : %d\n", N);

  printf("Before sorting : \n");
  print(test, N);

  quickSort(test, 0, N - 1, n_th);

  printf("After sorting : \n");
  print(test, N);

  return 0;
}

/**
 * Quicksort.
 * @param a The array to be sorted.
 * @param first The start of the sequence to be sorted.
 * @param last The end of the sequence to be sorted.
 * @param n_th The digit to sort by
 */
void quickSort(int a[], int first, int last, int n_th) {
  int pivotElement;

  if (first < last) {
    pivotElement = pivot(a, first, last, n_th);
    quickSort(a, first, pivotElement - 1, n_th);
    quickSort(a, pivotElement + 1, last, n_th);
  }
}

/**
 * Find and return the index of pivot element.
 * @param a The array.
 * @param first The start of the sequence.
 * @param last The end of the sequence.
 * @param n_th The digit to sort by
 * For example the third digit of 137
 * requires n_th to be 0.
 *
 */
int pivot(int a[], int first, int last, int n_th) {
  int i, p = first;
  int pivotElement = a[first];

  for (i = first + 1; i <= last; i++) {
    if (n_th_digit(a[i], n_th) <= n_th_digit(pivotElement, n_th)) {
      p++;
      swap(&a[i], &a[p]);
    }
  }

  swap(&a[p], &a[first]);

  return p;
}

/**
 * Swap the parameters.
 * @param a The first parameter.
 * @param a The second parameter.
 */
void swap(int* a, int* b) {
  // You still can use the swap that
  // does not uses an extra variable
  // from the C++ implementation.
  int temp = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = temp;
}

int n_th_digit(int number, int n) {
  if (number < 0)
    number *= -1;
  return fmod((number / pow(10, n)), 10);
}

/**
 * Print an array.
 * @param a The array.
 * @param N The size of the array.
 */
void print(int a[], const int N) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    printf("array[%d] = %d\n", i, a[i]);
}
```

I got the how to find the n-th digit from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410629/finding-a-specific-digit-of-a-number) and the quicksort from [here](http://gsamaras.wordpress.com/code/quicksort-cjavacprolog/).

Comment: I understood that sort the numbers based on their n-th digit. But how ? I have wanted idea or way to solve

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
void bubble_sort(int iarr[], int num) {
  ....
  if (iarr[j] > iarr[j + 1])
```

With

```
void bubble_sort(int iarr[], int num, int term) {
  unsigned pow10 = upow10(term - 1);
  ....
  if (compareu(iarr[j], iarr[j + 1], pow10) > 0)
```

---

```
// To calculate pow(10, x) quickly
static unsigned upow10(unsigned y) {
  unsigned z = 1;
  unsigned base = 10;
  while (y) {
    if (y & 1) {
      z *= base;
    }
    y >>= 1;
    base *= base;
  }
  return z;
}

int compareu(int a1, int a2, unsigned pow10) {
  unsigned b1 = abs(a1);
  unsigned b2 = abs(a2);
  b1 = (b1 / pow10) % 10;
  b2 = (b2 / pow10) % 10;
  if (b1 > b2) return 1;
  if (b1 < b2) return -1;
  return (a1 > a2) - (a1 < a2);
}
```

---

[Edit] per OP's update

Q: how can be the program sensed a number with zeros I mean for 1 program sense 0001 or 00001?
A:  That is part of the code that reads input which is not posted.  If code needs to distinguish between "0001" and "00001", then the whole problem is one of strings and not integers.  In that case save each element as a string and do compares from a textual point-of-view.

Yet I suspect that is not the true coding goal. Simply use arithmetical compares and not be concerned with differing leading zeros.

The `printf()` function is another matter.  To print *at least* `term` digits with leading `0`, use `"%0*d"`.

```
term = 2; // or 6 or 9, etc.
// printf("%5d", iarr[k]);
printf("%0*d ", term, iarr[k]);
```

Comment: Yes, lets convert the whole thing to a string just to extract a digit.  Oh, and lets do it over and over again.

Comment: If they're using bubble sort do you really think they will care about using strings to extract digits?

Comment: @Daniel Replaced with numeric approach.

Comment: Seems better, though I would personally extract that into its own function to get the nth digit. There is very little overhead to function calls, but high overhead to maintaining this code as it is.

Comment: @Daniel Replaced with faster numeric approach.  Of course `term` could be replaced with `pow10` and calculated only once.

Comment: @Daniel Performing separate calls to find the nth digit for the two terms does not take advantage of using a 1 time calculated common divisor like 10 for the 2nd term, and 1,000,000 for the 7th term.  Once this power-of-10 divisor is found, determining the nth digit is a simple division and mod.  Of course the 2 lines of `b = (b / pow10) % 10;` could be replace with `foo(b, pow10)` where `unsigned foo(unsigned x, unsigned pow10) { return (x/pow10)%10; }` per your suggestion to functional-ize where possible.